# Why does my image not display after adding a class name in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a slideshow using html javascript or probably css. But for some reason **once I add a class name, which is** `mySlides` **, my images don't display anymore.** The `script.js` is not doing anything.

Here is my HTML, very simple:

```
<div class="mySlides">
   <img src="TheTailoryimg/IMG_3649.JPG">
   <img src="img2.JPG">
   <img src="TheTailoryimg/img1.tif">
</div>
```

and here is my Javascript, I added an external js link at the top of the HTML like this `<script src="script.js"></script>`

Here is my js:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: ... And what does your CSS look like?

Comment: You want to apply `.mySlides` to the image tags, not the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Your code wants an object of `.mySlides`, then loops through all `.mySlides` on the page, hides them, then displays them as a carousel. So you want to apply `.mySlides` to the `img` tags, not the parent.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.star2.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/happy-days-770x470.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this before but it still doesn't work for me. Nothing is displayed after I add any form of "class ="

Comment: @Kat what do you mean "it still doesn't work for me"? Is my demo working? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: the images are not displayed on my local computer. Your demo works fine.

Comment: I just want the images to be displayed. But my local file shows me nothing no matter where I put class="mySlides"

Comment: so wait -- you're trying to use this on  localhost, or a local file//? the images display before you add the class to the parent element? Do you have any CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Images are showing up inside the Snippet I created with your code.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1">
</div>
```

Comment: hi! thank you! do you have any idea why adding a class name will not display the images?